# Change All Document Link Colors Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, styles, dhtml

Is there a way I can change all links on my page to a certain color at the same time? such as:

```
document.anchors.style.color = "red";
```

probably with an onclick function i'm thinking. No luck so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe dynamically create a css for that.

```
var styleElement = document.createElement("style");
styleElement.type = "text/css";
if (styleElement.styleSheet) {
  styleElement.styleSheet.cssText = "a { color: red }";
} else {
  styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("a { color: red; }"));
}
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

document.anchors return an array, you should loop through them.

```
var anchors = document.anchors;
for(var i=0, m=anchors.length; i<m; i++){
    anchors[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been answered already but well my version anyway :)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var ChangeColors = function() {
            var elem = document.createElement('style');
            elem.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
            var style = document.createTextNode("A, A:hover, A:visited { color: red; }")
            elem.appendChild(style);
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(elem);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#">Some Link</a><br />
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Some Other Link</a><br />
        <input type="button" onclick="ChangeColors();"/>
        <a href="#">Some Link 2</a><br />
        <a href="#">Some Link 3</a><br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: to the down voter: It'd be much appreciated if you could explain why you down voted this post. Thank you.